# My JSP page won't load CSS file

Tags: css, spring, spring-mvc, jsp

I Have Spring MVC application, I'm using Java config, no XML. My JSP cant access CSS file. I googled whole day, tried almost everything. When I inspect my page, in console there is error - **Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)** I'm using Wildfly server.

[image: folder structure]

**SpringConfig:**

```
package com.library.config;


import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;


@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.library")
public class SpringConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/resources/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/static/css/");
    }
}
```

**DispatcherInitializer:**

```
package com.library.config;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class DispatcherInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {


    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] {SpringConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] {"/"};
    }
}
```

**JSP page:**

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>

<c:set var="context" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"/>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Login Page</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="<c:url value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/static/css/style.css" />" rel="stylesheet">


</head>
<body>

<h2>${pageContext.request.contextPath}</h2>

<br>
<div class="row">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="login-register-form-section">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                <li class="active"><a href="#login" data-toggle="tab">Login</a></li>
                <li><a href="#register" data-toggle="tab">Register</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="login">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="">
                        <div class="form-group " >
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></div>
                                <input type="text" name="login_email" class="form-control" placeholder="Username or email" required="required" value="">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group ">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-key"></i></div>
                                <input type="password" name="login_password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="required">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="rememberMe">
                            <label for="rememberMe">Remember Me</label>
                            <a href="#" class="pull-right">Forgot password?</a>
                        </div>
                        <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-success btn-custom">

                    </form>
                </div>
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="register">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" id="form">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></div>
                                <select type="text" id="sex" name="gender" class="form-control">
                                    <option>Male</option>
                                    <option>Female</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group ">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-male"></i></div>
                                <input type="text" id="register_username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required="required" value="">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group ">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></div>
                                <input type="email" id="register_email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required="required" value="">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group ">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-skype"></i></div>
                                <input type="text" id="register_skype" class="form-control" placeholder="Skype name" required="required" value="">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group ">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></div>
                                <input type="password" id="register_password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="required">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <input type="submit" id="submitbtn" value="Register" class="btn btn-success btn-custom">
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <center><h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Your registration was successful! Please login!</h5></center>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" id="confirm" class="btn btn-primary">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seems like `webapp` is under `src` directory.

Comment: `webapp` is on the same level as `main`. This structure was generated by maven.

Comment: Try using  `<link href="/resources/static/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you posted with your question, I am starting off by making some assumptions/guesses about your project:

1. Your project is setup as a `Java` project.
2. You are using `Maven` to run your builds, with the package production set to: `<packaging>WAR</packaging>`.
3. After a successful build, a copy of `style.css` ends up in the following location: `/target/libraryproject/WEB-INF/classes/static/css/style.css`.

I think I'm pretty safe on the first 2, but that 3rd guess may not be correct, depending on how your build is setup. For example, the `libraryproject` part of the target path could actually be something like: `libraryproject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`. If so, you may have to make some adjustments to what follows, so please keep that in mind, but here are my suggestions:

### Step 1:

Change the existing `SpringConfig.addResourceHandlers` method, drop the `DEVELOPMENT_TIME` perspective, refactor the `resourceLocations` parameter to define a `RUNTIME` specification, and so that at `RUNTIME`, static resources are loaded from the root `classpath` in the `WAR` file:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
}
```

### Step 2:

Update the stylesheet `link` specification in `login.jsp` so that it loads `style.css` from the `WAR` file `resourceLocation` defined in Step 1:

```
<link href="<c:url value="css/style.css"/>" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Note how the path is relative to the `/static/` resource root location in the target build location, which stays the same in the `WAR`.

After those 2 changes, I think you'll be up and running. I hope so. Let me know if not and I'll try to give you a hand. I remember having the same problem, slogging at it for hours, and the frustrating 404 errors. It was painful - hope this helps you get the problem resolved -

Comment: I checked those 3 points and they are ok. I tried those 2 step but when I insert `<link href="<c:url value="css/style.css"/>" rel="stylesheet"/>` it gives me error on that value - Cannot resolve directory.

Comment: If you can give me a little more detail, I'll help you figure out what is happening-